# Infinite linear ordered set which doesn't include infinte well-ordered subsets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Need an example of such set.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about the negative integers, usual order? Verification that this has no infinite well-ordered subset should not be difficult.

Comment: @kushtibargo: And more generally, take any infinite well-ordered set and turn it around.

Comment: @kushtibargo: In fact, Brian's suggestion gives you all the examples.